# How to store data of size more than 20MB in Couchbase?

Tags: database, couchbase

Is there something like GRIDFS in Couchbase to store large data?
If we need to chunk the data do we need to do manually ?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment there is no direct mapping to a feature like GRIDFS in Couchbase. Let me know what you are trying to accomplish and I can update my answer with some potential solutions.

Comment: I have a document of size about 100MB , how to store that in Couchbase and retrieve it back?

Comment: Short answer is: If you don't need to query the document, compress it first, that should be enough to bring it down to 20MB mark. If you need to query the file, you will definitely need to divide it into smaller pieces. Query 100MB JSON files will put too much pressure on both couchbase and mongo.